Automatic annotation of *non-native* semi-spontaneous speech
I wonder if there is any tool for automatically annotating L2-semi-spontaneous speech (practically said, to produce a TextGrid file from a sound file (.wav) and a text file containing the transcription of the sound file´s content).
Most of the tools are not set for L2 speech, and a manual annotation of a huge amount of data is very time-consuming. Have you ever faced this problem? Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance for your attention, and I look forward to hearing your opinions and suggestions.

non-native speech depends on the L1 of the speaker. Each language will give rise to typical mistakes in an L2. Ergo, this is a fool's errand. [idiom] Also, what is semi-spontaneous speech? Speech is either spontaneous or not.

Most speech-to-text programs can handle foreign accents in English. Have you tried them?
